# LINQ select in C# dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have next dictionary in C#

```
Dictionary<string, object> subDictioanry = new Dictionary<string, object>();

List<Dictionary<string, string>> subList = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();

subList.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"valueLink", "link1"},
    {"valueTitle","title1"}
});
subList.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"valueLink", "link2"},
    {"valueTitle","title2"}
});
subList.Add(new Dictionary<string, string>(){
    {"valueLink", "link3"},
    {"valueTitle","title3"}
});

subDictioanry.Add("title", "title");
subDictioanry.Add("name", "name");
subDictioanry.Add("fieldname1", subList);

Dictionary<string, object> exitDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>();
exitDictionary.Add("first", subDictioanry);
exitDictionary.Add("second", subDictioanry);
```

Is it possible to get all "valueTitle" with help of LINQ select?

UPDATE:
Sorry, i should write it first - i need to get result from exitDictionary, not from subList

Comment: This would be way easier to reason about if you used classes instead of dictionaries. Just saying.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you are searching by the `fieldname1` value, try this:

```
var r = exitDictionary
   .Select(i => i.Value).Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()
   .Where(d => d.ContainsKey("fieldname1"))
   .Select(d => d["fieldname1"]).Cast<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>()
   .SelectMany(d1 => 
       d1
        .Where(d => d.ContainsKey("valueTitle"))
        .Select(d => d["valueTitle"])
        .Where(v => v != null)).ToList();
```

If you are looking by the type of the value in the `subDictionary` (`Dictionary<string, object>` explicitly), you may do this:

```
var r = exitDictionary
   .Select(i => i.Value).Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()
   .SelectMany(d=>d.Values)
   .OfType<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>()
   .SelectMany(d1 => 
       d1
        .Where(d => d.ContainsKey("valueTitle"))
        .Select(d => d["valueTitle"])
        .Where(v => v != null)).ToList();
```

Both alternatives will return:

```
title1
title2
title3
title1
title2
title3
```

Answer (score 12):

One way would be to first flatten the list with a `SelectMany`:

```
subList.SelectMany(m => m).Where(k => k.Key.Equals("valueTitle"));
```

Answer (score 3):

This will return all the values matching your key `valueTitle`

```
subList.SelectMany(m => m).Where(kvp => kvp.Key == "valueTitle").Select(k => k.Value).ToList();
```

Comment: This is incorrect. `kvp` would not be a `KeyValuePair`, it would be a `Dictionary<string, string>`. You are missing a `SelectMany` to flatten the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = exitDictionary
            .Select(p => p.Value).Cast<Dictionary<string, object>>()
            .SelectMany(d => d)
            .Where(p => p.Key == "fieldname1")
            .Select(p => p.Value).Cast<List<Dictionary<string,string>>>()
            .SelectMany(l => l)
            .SelectMany(d=> d)
            .Where(p => p.Key == "valueTitle")
            .Select(p => p.Value)
            .ToList();
```

This also works, and easy to understand.